# как увеличить расширенный раздел Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, gparted

Необходимо увеличить размер расширенного раздела из не размеченного пространства без потери данных загружен с liveCD, гугл есть, но видимо я слишком туп  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Выделяете расширенный раздел и тыкаете «Изменить размер»

Comment: там пункты меню не активны

Comment: Я проверил у себя — у меня активны, покажите скриншот тогда

Comment: при активном мню скриншот не делается

Comment: Делается, вы просто не умеете их делать :) А вообще ключики на имеющемся скриншоте намекают, что вам наверно следует сперва выключить swap, потому что он используется и раздел в итоге занят

Comment: нужно увeличить /dev/sda4

Comment: Выключайте swap и увеличивайте

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрейшей души человек, все получилось!